# Can Selenium handle Angular 7 applications?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, angular

Our application is using Angular7.
Now we can thinking to automate out application with Selenium

Can Selenium handle our application?

Answer (score 3):

With Selenium you can interact with web-browsers to drive web-applications. Angular7 result into web-applications, so yes it should be able to handle it.

But, Angular has its own layer on top of Selenium to make testing Angular applications easier: https://www.protractortest.org/

Other reads:

- https://medium.com/@dhormale/automate-end-to-end-e2e-testing-for-angular-7-using-protractor-jasmine-4ce171aaeedc

Comment: ok. Thanks for the answer, for suppose if we use selenium for angular 7 applications  is there any problems appear further i mean any errors or warnings?

Comment: No problem will happen, but Selenium is not best tool per se, because it does not know about the Angular internals. Protactor can leverage the Angular framework in order to create faster and cleaner scripts.